# The conda environment in pycharm can not found the dedicated python interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I opened an existing project with `pycharm`, then I switched the python interpreter to a `conda` environment I havd created in terminal: `cc_env_python3.7`
[image: Python interpreter]

Then I opened the terminal console in `pyCharm`, one can see that the conda environment is now activated:
[image]

However, the default python in this conda environment is still the local python:
[image]

The problem only exist in the `pyCharm` shell, when I activate the conda environment with Terminal, everything works fine.

How can I open a pyCharm shell with default python assigned correctly?

Comment: The terminal doesn't use the IDE interpreter value, only what is defined in your zshrc. You can install packages and run the code from the IDE instead of the terminal, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: In pycharm shell, you can see that the conda env is already activated, but the desired python interpreter can not be found. But in terminal, everything works correctly. I just want to use my desired interpreter in the IDE@OneCricketeer

Comment: You mean cannot be found with `which`? That inspects your terminal `PATH`, not the IDE settings

Comment: can not found in the IDE shell. @OneCricketeer

Comment: I see no error in your question that says it cannot be found... Only see `which` returning the `/usr/bin/python` . Did you try to `cd` to where you created the conda env? And find its own bin folder?

Comment: In terminal, `which python`  returns the `/Users/cheng/opt/anaconda3/envs/cc_env_python3.7...`, this is what I desired @OneCricketeer